# Suite Script 2.0 - Handling Duplicate Fields in Saved Search

Tags: duplicates, field, netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I have a Transaction's saved search, in which I have used Account fields three times with custom label. please see attached screenshot.
[image]

but when pulling data for this saved search using suite script 2.0, netsuite returns first account field as 'account', second as 'account_1' and third as 'account_2', please see attached screenshot of json output
[image]

So I am not able to determine which account is 'Account Two' and which one is 'Account Three' (based on my screenshot), and this is causing my mapping screen failure.

Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think here it is showing as  Account_one  as Account and Account_two as Account_1 and Account 3 as the Account_2..  Please try to get the values from  of account records in script  and match it with your Account records.. You can easily find out...

Comment: Yes @Phanikumar

Answer (score 1):

Is your saved search filtering (criteria) for Main Line?

Comment: No, currently I don't have any filter on my saved search

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, here is which one is which saved search column

- Account is first occurance  - (with no label)
- Account_1 is the 2nd occurance of the same field (with Label Account Three)
- Account_2 is the 3rd occurance of the same field (with Label Account Two)